# Performing different behaviors based on object type in an array list

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm implementing a sort of exam grading system. I'll streamline the information as much as possible. 
Every exam can have a true or false question (boolean), a fill in the blanks question (String array containing all the choices) and a multiple choice question (also a string array containing all the choices).

Every student that takes the exam has an answer sheet. The answers can be a boolean (for true or false) or a string array (for fill in the blanks and multiple choice questions as multiple choice questions can have multiple answers as well). Every time a student answers a question it gets added to the answer sheet.

Now the grading happens this way. For true and false questions, its simple. If the answer is right award the points. But for fill in the blanks and multiple choice there's partial credit, if the student gets 2/3 of the choices right for example, he gets 2/3 of the points.

I have a method called getExamScore(Exam a). This is where the student gets graded. I decided to create an answer key array list that contains all the right answers for each of the questions. The question number being the index. Example:

```
`ArrayList<Object> answerKey = getExamAnswerKey(Exam a);`
System.out.println(answerKey);
//Outputs
[false, false, true, [A, C, D], [int, boolean, double];
```

I know having an array list of objects is usually bad practice but I couldn't think of a better way to collect all the answers to compare the student answers too. I had a similar arrayList for all of the student's answers:

```
ArrayList<Object> studentAnswers = getStudentAnswer(Exam a);
System.out.println(studentAnswers);
//Outputs
[False, true, true, [A, C], [int, boolean]]
```

Now this is where I'm stuck. When I'm grading this in my getExamScore() method, I wanna check the answerKey to the studentAnswers and see how many points to award. But it's not a simple a case as just saying `if(studentAnswers[index].equals(answerKey[index])) score++;`

Because the string arrays can't be compared like that. So I wanted to have conditions that if the answerKey[index] and studentAnswers[index] was a string array, have a for loop that compares the two and award the appropriate points. If it was a true false answer, simple compare the values and if its right, award the points. For example the sample student's points would look like this:

```
[1, 0, 1, 2/3, 2/3] for all the respective problems (partial credit included)
```

Can someone suggest a way to achieve this grading design? I'm open to critique on my data structure choices as well. I know ArrayList of objects has a bad code smell to it but I really couldn't think of any other way to collect all the answers.

Comment: You are better off introducing a class; that way it *is* as easy as `if(student.answers[index].equals(teacher.answers[index])) score++;`
Btw, isn't your String array (`[A, C, D]`) always in the 4th position of the ArrayList?

Comment: Please try to narrow your problem and make your question more clear: lots of your introduction is unnecessary and your title could be improved. Otherwise, it's a well-written question that shows effort of understanding on your part.

Comment: I agree with the need to narrow this down. It could be *a lot* shorter (one paragraph + the code) and lose no value or clarity.

Comment: I did push the length with all the words but I wanted to adequately explain my conundrum instead of having to clarify time and again in the comments. I'll edit it soon as I have some time though. Thanks

Comment: @Kenney Can you explain how adding another class would help? Let's say I create a AnswerType class. Could you expand on how I would go about using this to award points? The partial credit aspect is the one thing that prompted me to do this and treat them as separate objects. I need to be able to compare every element in the array to the corresponding answer key.

Comment: I would say what you're dealing with here is `GradingStrategy`-ies of `Question`s which have `Answer`s. It takes a bit of code to do but it's a clean solution. To get the exam score you would grade each question based on the answers and appropriate strategies. It's flexible because you can generically store the Q&As and have any number of strategies without altering the main part of your code. You'd simply be able to add a question of another type and add another strategy. [Strategy Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/strategy-pattern.html).

Answer (score -1):

Your question as I understand it (you should probably simplify it to make it more clear) is:

> Given an `ArrayList<Object>`, how can I perform different behavior based on what type of object is in each index of the ArrayList?

The answer being that you can use the `instanceof` operator to identify the subtype of an object.

```
for (Object answer : studentAnswers) {
    if (answer instanceof String[]) {
        // Perform string array grading behavior
    } else if (answer instanceof boolean) {
        // Perform boolean grading behavior
    }
}
```

Comment: There are far better ways to do as you say without using `instanceof`. In this case it seems to be trading one smelly type for another.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Constructive criticism is welcome. Criticism that tells me I'm just plain wrong is not helpful.

Comment: That's not what the comment is doing. I didn't say you're "plain wrong" as that would suggest that it wouldn't work; which it will. I won't repeat myself but urge you to read it again and consider the constructiveness of if.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I see "your implementation is poor in comparison to other potential implementations." which is not constructive - constructiveness would tell me (or, frankly, the OP, since he's the one that needs to know) what the best implementation would be.

Comment: Whatever, you're expecting me to act as if we're co-workers. It's not my responsibility to teach you something you should know if you're answering the question and answering the question is out since to do it "properly" is too much (broad), but since you insist. Consider that you haven't addressed what the problem is. They're concerned about having a list of Objects (valid). You offer a solution that builds smell on top of that in the form of a inflexible-hard-to-maintain approach. An additional class or two is obvious and adding a strategy is another addition.